# Simplify jQuery code

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have these two codes I've done to load data on scroll and display it in two different divs (.cat_a and .cat_b).

Data is stored as objects in a json file and printed out 3 at a time from get_data.php.

I'm not familiar with JS and jQuery, is there a way to simplify and clean them?

Load data on (div class=".cat_a"):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var flag = 0;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'get_data.php',
      data: {
        'offset': 0,
        'limit': 3,
        'cat': "cat_a"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.cat_a').append(data);
        flag += 3;
      }

    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'get_data.php',
          data: {
            'offset': flag,
            'limit': 3,
            'cat': "cat_a"
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('.cat_a').append(data);
            flag += 3;
          }
        });

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Load data on (div class=".cat_b"):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var flag = 0;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'get_data.php',
      data: {
        'offset': 0,
        'limit': 3,
        'cat': "cat_b"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('.cat_b').append(data);
        flag += 3;
      }

    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {

        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'get_data.php',
          data: {
            'offset': flag,
            'limit': 3,
            'cat': "cat_b"
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $('.cat_b').append(data);
            flag += 3;
          }
        });

      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: moev the ajax call into a function and call it where you need to instead of duplicating the code. add the category id to the list (ie data-category-id), add something like data-endless-scroller to the list, use a selector for that in your js to start a scrollable list and get the category id to use in the ajax calls. you should now have only one general js file (for both lists) which is much shorter than what you have atm. Then I'd consider why you need to do the first ajax call, can't you just populate the initial list on page load?

Comment: **I'm not familiar with JS and jQuery** - it's better if you do at least a basic research and demonstrate an effort solving it. Otherwise it looks like a homework to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the redundancies in your code and added comments.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //create a method that can be called for each category
  //it also scopes a flag variable for each one
  function getDataFor(category) {
    var flag = 0;

    //the ajax call is made the same for the initial call and on scroll
    //so that's another method
    function getData() {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get_data.php',
        data: {
          'offset': 0,
          'limit': 3,
          'cat': category
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('.' + category).append(data);
          flag += 3;
        }
      });
    }

    getData(); //do our initial ajax call for the category

    //these jQuery variables are made multiple times in the scroll event
    //so we can cache them for some performance
    var $window = $(window);
    var $document = $(document);

    $window.on('scroll', function() {
      if ($window.scrollTop() >= $document.height() - $window.height()) {
        //call our ajax again on scroll when needed
        getData();
      }
    });
  }

  //call the method for each category we want to perform the logic on
  getDataFor('cat_a');
  getDataFor('cat_b');
});
```

Comment: thank you, it works good! I only changed the value of 'offset' 0 with flag at line 14 to load all of the content and not to repeat the first 3 objects all the way !